# Ownership of values passed to overloaded PartialEq

Tags: rust, operator-overloading, ownership, borrowing

I have been playing around with overloading some operators. I ran into a situation that I don't quite understand. When implementing the trait `PartialEq` for my struct `Value`, I noticed that the implementation below works and doesn't move the values, allowing me to continue to use the values after using the `==` operator on them without passing references of the values into the operator.

On the other hand, this doesn't work for the implementation of the `Neg` trait (or `Add`, `Sub`, etc.). In order to use the `-` operator without moving the value, I have to implement the `Neg` trait on references to the `Value` struct.

Why can I implement the `PartialEq` trait without having to worry about a move when not passing in a reference to the values, but when implementing the `Neg` trait I do need to worry? Am I implementing the `Neg` trait incorrectly? Is there a subtlety to the `PartialEq` trait that I am overlooking?

Here is my code:

```
struct Value {
    x: i32
}

impl PartialEq for Value {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Value) -> bool {
        if self.x == other.x {
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
    }
}
impl Eq for Value {}

impl Neg for &Value {
    type Output = Value;

    fn neg(self) -> Self::Output {
        Value {
            x: -self.x
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v1: Value = Value {x: 1};
    let v2: Value = Value {x: 2};
    let equal = v1 == v2; // Not passing a reference, but also able to use v1
    let v3 = -&v1;
    let v4 = -&v1; // Works because I am passing a reference. If I change the implementation of Neg to 'impl Neg for Value' and remove the reference here and in the line above (for v3), it will complain that v1 had been moved (as expected).
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a subtlety to the `PartialEq` trait that I am overlooking?

`PartialEq`'s methods take `self` and `other` by reference (`&self` and `other: &T` in the signature), while `Neg`, `Add`, `Sub`, etc. take `self` and (for binary operators) `other` by value (`self` and `other: T` in the signature). `v1 == v2` desugars to `PartialEq::eq(&v1, &v2)`, while `!v1` desugars to `Neg::neg(v1)`.

The reason why you might want `Neg` to take ownership of the passed value is if the value has allocated dynamic memory (via `Box`, `Vec`, etc.). In that case, it might be more efficient to mutate `self` and then return `self` (or another object reusing the dynamic memory in the case where the `Output` type is different from the `Self` type) instead of allocating a new object (which would require new dynamic memory allocations), even if the original value is not used after the operation.

On the other hand, `PartialEq`'s methods always return a `bool`. A `bool` doesn't allocate any dynamic memory, therefore there is no gain in passing the parameters by value. It's not expected that testing whether two objects are equal would need to mutate either or both of the objects, hence why the parameters are shared references.

> Am I implementing the `Neg` trait incorrectly?

No, but you might want to consider implementing `Neg` for both `Value` and `&Value` (especially if you're writing a library for others to use).

If your type is cheap to copy (i.e. it's small and doesn't use dynamic memory), consider implementing `Clone` and `Copy` (possibly by deriving them) as well. This way, you can pass values to the operators without moving the value to the operator, because the value will be copied instead.

Comment: You may also implement `Copy` if your struct is small and doesn't need any special logic for copying (which would be cloning in that case).